# Fourier coefficients of eigenforms

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms

How does one prove that the fourier coefficients of a normalized eigenform for Hecke operators $T_p$ on $S_k(N)$ all lie in a fixed number field?

If the proof is lengthy, a reference to a book that has the proof will do. Thanks!

Comment: There is a proof in Shimura's "Introduction to the arithmetic theory of automorphic functions".

Comment: @NPS : Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794325/why-is-the-coefficient-field-of-a-normalized-hecke-form-a-number-field