# Why does the coefficient field of a normalized Hecke form a number field?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Let $f \in S_k(N,\chi)^{\mathrm{new}}$ be a normalized Hecke cusp form (i.e $a_1(f)=1$ and $f$ is an eigenform under Hecke actions). My question is, why is the coefficient field  $K_f=\Bbb Q(\{a_n(f)\}_{n \geq 1})$ a number field (without using the deep fact that $f$ gives a Galois representation)? It's easy to see $K_f$ is algebraic. Many notes always state this result but don't give a proof.

Comment: The Hecke operators are linear transformations on finite dimensional vector spaces of modular forms, so just linear algebra.

Comment: @sharding4 But there are infinitely many operators.

Comment: True but since they commute with each other they stabilize each other's eigenspaces.  Take a look at Lemma 5.3 in Milne [Modular Functions and Modular Forms](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/MF.pdf)

Comment: @sharding4 Sorry could you provide some details? $\bar {\Bbb Q} \hookrightarrow \text{End}(S_k(N,\chi))$ also satisfies what you say. This lemma could only prove $K_f$ is a totally real algebraic extension.

Comment: @zzy : how do you see easily that $K_f$ is algebraic? For me, the proof of this fact has to rely on the existence of some integral structure on $S_k(\Gamma_1(N))$, which then imply that the integral Hecke algebra is finitely generated as $\Bbb Z$-algebra (even as a $\Bbb Z$-module) — and this solves your problem.

Comment: @Watson i don't think the existence of integral structure can directly implies the Hecke algebra is finite generated as $\Bbb Z$-algebra. $K_f$ is algebraic as eigenvalue is algebraic ($a_n(f)$ satisfies the characterestic polynomial of $T_n$). I know the proof that $T_n$ has integral coeffecient but don't know how to prove $K_f$ is algebraic.

Comment: @zzy : You're right about the fact that an integral structure on $S_k$ doesn't give _directly_ the finiteness of the Hecke algebra, but it is a main tool, though. However, how do you know that $T_n$ has integral coefficients (more precisely I guess that you mean that its characteristic polynomial, as endomorphism on the space of modular forms, has integer coefficients)?

Comment: @sharding4 : I think that the finite dimensionality of the $\Bbb C$-vector space $S_k$ of modular forms is far from being sufficient. You need an integral structure on $S_k$ and then prove it is a free abelian group of finite rank.

Comment: @zzy : Again,  how do you know that $T_n$ has integral coefficients? For me, this is far from being obvious…

Comment: @Watson My vague idea is regarding modular form as sections of a coherent sheaf, and by flat base change we have $H^k(X_{\Bbb C} ,\mathcal{F}_{\Bbb C})=H^k(X,F)\otimes_{\Bbb Q} \Bbb C$.

Comment: @zzy : this seems to be exactly what is explained on p. 111 from Diamond–Im's paper. So anyway, I guess that the answer I provided cannot be simplified much more.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the integral Hecke algebra $T = \Bbb Z[T_n : n \geq 1]$, which is a commutative $\Bbb Z$-subalgebra of 
$A := \mathrm{End}_{\Bbb C\text{-lin.}}\left[ S_k(\Gamma) \right]$, where $\Gamma := \Gamma_1(N)$.

> **Lemma**. The algebra $T$ is finite over $\Bbb Z$ (i.e. its additive group is a finitely generated $\Bbb Z$-module).

Before providing the proof of this lemma, here is how it solves your problem.
Since $f$ is a normalized eigenform, we can consider the map
$$\lambda : T_n \mapsto a_n(f) = \lambda_n(f)$$ such that $T_n(f) = \lambda_n(f) f$.

It provides a morphism of $\Bbb Z$-algebras $T \to \Bbb C$. The image of $\lambda$ is therefore a finitely generated subgroup of $(\Bbb C, +)$. This implies that the field generated by $\mathrm{Im}(\lambda)$ is not only an algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q$ (see [prop. 5.27](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/MF.pdf#page=79) for a direct proof when $N=1$), but is actually a number field (it is generated by finitely many algebraic elements).

---

**Sketch of the proof of the lemma.**

It relies on the fact that $S_k(\Gamma_1(N))$ is finite dimensional over $\Bbb C$, so $A \cong M_n(\Bbb C)$ (for some $n \geq 1$) is a finitely generated (non-commutative) $\Bbb C$-algebra — it is even finitely generated as $\Bbb C$-vector space. But here we want to show that $T$ is a finitely generated module over $\Bbb Z$.

The $q$-expansion at $i\infty$ provides an injective map of $\Bbb C$-vector spaces $j : S_k(\Gamma) \to \Bbb C[\![q]\!]$. Define 
$S_k(\Gamma, \Bbb Z) := j^{-1}(\Bbb Z[\![q]\!])$ as the subgroup of cusp forms with integer Fourier coefficients.

The lemma now follows from the following three facts (which I simply quote — when $k=2$ or $N=1$, one can provide easier arguments, I guess):

1. The $\Bbb Z$-module $S_k(\Gamma, \Bbb Z)$ is preserved under the action of any Hecke operator $T_n$. [See Diamond–Im, Proposition 12.4.1].
2. The $\Bbb Z$-module $S_k(\Gamma, \Bbb Z)$ contains a basis of the $\Bbb C$-vector space $S_k(\Gamma)$. [See Diamond–Im, Proposition 12.3.8].
3. We have a natural isomorphism of $\Bbb C$-vector spaces $S_k(\Gamma, \Bbb Z) \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb C \cong S_k(\Gamma)$. [See Diamond–Im, Equation 12.3.5].

Indeed, the first fact implies the existence of a morphism of rings (i.e. $\Bbb Z$-algebras, possibly non-commutative)
$$g : T \to A' := \mathrm{End}_{\Bbb Z\text{-lin.}}\left[ S_k(\Gamma, \Bbb Z) \right],$$
and the second fact ensures injectivity of $g$.

By the second and third facts, the $\Bbb Z$-module $S_k(\Gamma, \Bbb Z)$ is a free of finite rank, say $\Bbb Z^m$, it follows that $A' \cong \Bbb Z^{m^2}$ as abelian groups, and therefore $(T,+)$ is a finitely generated abelian group (see exercise 6.5.1 in Diamond–Shurman, p. 239).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. $\operatorname{Im}T$ in $A$ is f.g as $\Bbb C$-algebra, how does this imply  $\operatorname{Im}T$ in $T \rightarrow \Bbb C$ is f.g as $\Bbb Z$-algebra?

Comment: @zzy : you may check my new answer. I don't think there is an obvious solution to your request.

Comment: (Side note: if $m$ is the dimension of $S_k(\Gamma)$ over $\Bbb C$, then fact 2 yields an inclusion $\Bbb Z^m \subset S_k(\Gamma, \Bbb Z) \subset \Bbb C^m$. Tensoring the first embedding over $\Bbb C$ gives an isomorphism of $\Bbb C$-vector spaces, so this embedding is actually an iso of abelian groups.

Comment: Thank you! The article you mentioned uses a lot of modular curves...

Comment: @zzy : yes, but if you want the cases $k \neq 2$, it might be necessary (I am not aware of any other way of approaching the algebraicity of Hecke eigenvalues). If $k=2$, you can use the first homology of $X_1(N)$ with integer coefficients to provide a direct proof (see Diamond–Shurman).

Comment: Thank you again, now the eigenforms and some forms with integral coefficients gives two basis of the modular form space. Do we know the transition matrix ?

Comment: @zzy : I don't know the transition matrix. Maybe you could ask a new question about this.

Comment: Anyway, Thank you.

Comment: @Watson You don't need to invoke the theory of modular curves as algebraic varieties over $\mathbf{Q}$ in order to prove algebraicity of Hecke eigenvalues. There is a much more elementary argument using group cohomology.(for any $k \ge 2$ this works directly, and for $k = 1$ you use the ring structure of modular forms.)

Comment: Dear @DavidLoeffler, thank you for your interesting comment. I've seen [your previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53596/) for $k=1$, but do you have a reference for an elementary proof when $k \geq 2$ (and $N$ arbitrary)?

Comment: (The only proofs I've seen are all using the lattice of modular forms with integer coefficients, e.g. Cohen, Stromberg Modular Forms, A Classical Approach, proposition 10.6.2, which doesn't use the modular curves, nor cohomology when $N=1$).